# MediaPlayer lagging, if launched from a service?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a service that launches an AlertDialog playing a video at a given time.

If there is **nothing** on the background (i.e. no applications/activities at all) playback is smooth but if there is **any** application underneath it accumulates about 50ms delay per second of playback. This is also true for a blank dummy activity in the background. CPU/GPU utilisation is very low throughout.

Has anybody seen this issue? Any suggestions?

**NOTE**: This is a **custom application** running on an Android 5.1 ROM which is meant to be used internally within my company so no need to point out displaying videos in AlertDialogs is intrusive for the user..

Comment: Consider using ExoPlayer instead. It's the evolution of MediaPlayer, and of course, more advanced

Comment: thanks Adrian but I thought ExoPlayer was based on MediaPlayer and just added extensions for DRM schemes and optimisations online? My movie is local

Comment: It's not based on MediaPlayer. I suggest you to take a look at it. It could simplify your coding. It can also play local videos with few lines of code. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

Comment: tried it and looks indeed better, thanks!

Comment: Happy to help! :)